# xterm commands (ls, cd, ...) unable to access Desktop, Documents after updating to Catalina

Tags: macos

I have been using the beta versions of Catalina, and mostly have not had any problems.  However, I often run XQuartz and use several xterms.  These are run from TWM.  Before Catalina I would be able to run ls, cd, vi, and other shell commands from within an xterm, even on the Desktop and Documents folder.  I have added XQuartz to the list of apps for Full Disk Access in the Preferences.  That doesn't fix the problem.  I have also given /opt/X11/bin/xterm Full Disk Access, but that doesn't fix it either.  Can anyone suggest what I might do to give the xterm commands permission to access these folders?  Thank you.

Comment: Might it be that you ended up on the wrong site? What does that question have to do with Emacs?

Comment: Maybe try a site such as unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I see now that I was wrong to come here.  But unix is not the same as macOS Catalina.  Can you suggest the correct stackexchange.com site?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution (at least for me) was to add the binary xquartz to the list of app with "Full Disk Access" (in the "Privacy" tab of the "Security and Privacy" setting of the "System Preferences"). The path to the binary is:

/opt/X11/bin/Xquartz

I also added

/opt/X11/bin/xinit

since it's a running process, although I don't think it is needed...

However, I am still having problems accessing iClouds folders (Document, Desktop, etc.)

Comment: Coppelius, I appreciate your answer.  However, I'm a little confused.  First, I thought Xquartz is in the Applications folder.  I do have a copy of Xquartz in /opt/X11/bin.  Are they the same?  Second, I had already added my application/Xquartz to Full Disk Access, and that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Okay, I verified that Xquartz in my Dock is located in /Applications.  So the two copies of Xquartz are potentially different.  When I'm running Xquartz, I'm running the version that's in /Applications.

Comment: The one in your application folder is more or less a script that launches the other one (and does bunch of other stuff). If you use the ps command, you'll see that the X11 that is actually running is from opt/X11/bin. From what I can piece together, the problem is getting access to iCloud drives. I stores all my Documents and Desktop files in iCloud, where X11 does not have permission (somehow, Terminal does). I can access the other files (in my /Users/xxxx  folder, or in Downloads).

Comment: My problem is not with iCloud, but rather with a USB drive.  I cannot cd to the drive from an X11 xterm, but doing so with Terminal is no problem.  It used to work before I started upgrading to the Catalina betas.

Comment: I gave Full Disk Access to /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz and /opt/X11/bin/xinit, and that didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Catalina's new enhanced security that prevents apps from accessing Documents, Desktop, Downloads, external & network volumes, etc, etc, without granting permission.

For some reason, X11 apps (or XQuartz itself) don't ask for permission to be granted when you try to access those folders. And it doesn't seem possible to add an application to the Privacy panel in System Preferences (the + - icons are greyed out, even with padlock unlocked).

Comment: I agree that it doesn't seem possible to add an application to Files and Folders in the Privacy panel.  However, I've added XQuartz, xterm, and ls, to the Full Disk Access.  The +/- is not greyed out there.  And that doesn't fix the problem.  I guess we need to wait for an update from X11, or maybe XQuartz?  Thanks for your answer, by the way.

Comment: Maybe, just like Emacs on OS X is actually run through a `ruby` process, and permissions need to be granted for `ruby`, there is another process that is controlling these. I have no idea what the process would be, though...

Answer (score 1):

A fix for me to let the XQuartz xterm run "ls" inside the Documents folder was to give my current shell "/bin/bash" full disk access permission in the "Security and Privacy" tab of System Preferences.  I tried all other X11-related startup processes with no luck.

NOTE - as reported elsewhere you can use "Command-Shift-." to show hidden folders like /bin in the Finder window that is opened when adding an app.

Comment: Strangely enough ... this worked for me too ... even though I'm actually using /bin/tcsh for a shell.  It's frustrating that you need to track down which application is actually accessing the OS (this breaks the abstraction models of the system).

Answer (score 0):

For those who switched to the new `zsh`, please add `/bin/zsh` to the full disk access. It finally worked out for me...

Answer (score 0):

I found it necessary and sufficient to add /bin/bash (using Command+Shift+G to get to /bin) to the "Full Disk Access" list even though I'm running /usr/local/bin/bash. (Adding /usr/local/bin/bash was neither necessary nor sufficient.) ?!